# AVPlayer not forwarding streaming track in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, avplayer

I'm having an issue with AVPlayer not **playing** in the background.

Here's the details:

I have an AVPlayer object and an AVPlayerItem as an instance variable of my view controller to stream music from links stored in the NSMutableArray, *linkArray*. When the user taps a track a track in a UITableView, both objects are instantiated like so:

```
musicPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[linkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:musicPlayerItem];
```

...And it plays perfectly. Whenever the track finishes while the app is **active** it'll skip fine, or when I manually trigger the app to skip track (whether it's active or backgrounded). But, when the app is in the background (including when the device is locked) it will not play the next track when it skips.

So, it skips to the next track on its own but doesn't play it. I either have to make the app active again or invoke the playing (via the headphone controls or the system-wide music controls).

Here is the code for the skipTrack method that is called both when manually invoked or by the system when the song reaches the end of the track:

```
        if (nowPlaying == [linkArray count]-1) {
            nowPlaying = 0;
            musicPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[linkArray objectAtIndex:0]]];
            player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:musicPlayerItem];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"NowPlaying (before increment: %i", nowPlaying);
            //If not, increment nowPlaying by one and play
            nowPlaying++;
            NSLog(@"NowPlaying (after increment: %i", nowPlaying);
            musicPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[linkArray objectAtIndex:nowPlaying]]];
            player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:musicPlayerItem];
     }
```

Really hope someone can help me with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that because you've enabled your app to play audio in the background it will stay active while music is playing. As soon as the music stops it will be suspended. So you  need to request time to execute tasks in the background **as soon as the song stops** (most players have a callback function for when the song completes, put this code at the beginning). So your code would look something like this...

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskID = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you.
    // stopped or ending the task outright.
    [application endBackgroundTask:newTaskID];
    newTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];];

if (nowPlaying == [linkArray count]-1) {
        nowPlaying = 0;
        musicPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[linkArray objectAtIndex:0]]];
        player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:musicPlayerItem];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NowPlaying (before increment: %i", nowPlaying);
        //If not, increment nowPlaying by one and play
        nowPlaying++;
        NSLog(@"NowPlaying (after increment: %i", nowPlaying);
        musicPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[linkArray objectAtIndex:nowPlaying]]];
        player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:musicPlayerItem];
 }

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:newTaskID];
newTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;'
```

The "beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:" method will grant you some time to do things while in the background. If your time runs out the block of code that was sent to that method is executed. You need to include that incase something goes wrong and you need to clean up the task. Read more about it at the dev library: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. n00b question but, what datatype is _newTaskID_? I read the iOS Programming Guide that you attached and its description was a bit confusing. Thanks

Comment: Oops I should've included that, it's a UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier. So just declare it as "UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskID"

Comment: OK, done that. And I call this inside the _applicationDidEnterBackground:_ method in my view controller? Thanks again.

Comment: No I believe you can include it in your normal "playback done" or track skip method. No need to make a special case for it.

Comment: Got it working! I removed the middle section (where you actually do the track skipping) and just added it to the _applicationDidEnterBackground_ method in my AppDelegate.m. Thanks **so** much for your help! :D

Comment: Well you have to be careful because it wont last forever. Eventually the background task time will run out, and your tracks wont skip in the bg until you unlock the device. I would "beginBackgroundTask.." in the code that gets called right after a track finishes, and when your done skipping call the "endBackgroundTask" part. But I'll leave it to you. Good luck!!